# What is a possible organization in a cyberpunk setting that is equivalent to an adventurer guild in a fantasy setting?

Tags: science-fiction, organizations, cyberpunk

I'm thinking of a cyberpunk world where cities are controlled by mega corporations, not government. Although they existed, they are just mere puppet, controlled by said mega corporations. Of course mercenary and private security organization existed too. While the organization I'm trying to make will work like an adventurer guild, they will have to follow some rules and regulation set by the higher authority. They will mainly do the stuff that are either too cheap and too simple for the mercenary organization to take on or maybe help the mercenary in some of their mission as extra hands. But most of the time they will do stuff like searching for missing person, delivery request, or cheap escort request.

Comment: You may want to read Steven Pressfield's [_The Profession_](http://www.stevenpressfield.com/the-profession/). In that novel, Force Insertion is a stateless private army; essentially, one of the mega-corporations which functions somewhat like as an adevnturer's guild. (And like a real guild it has a monopoly on mercenary military work.) Plus it is a very good book.

Comment: You should look at the shadowrunners from the shadowrun RPG that fits your description perfectly.http://shadowrun.wikia.com/wiki/Shadowrunners

Comment: @John  That Shadowrunner is the closest to what I need at the moment. I just need to make it more accessible to the non-shady part of the world. Thanks, mate~!

Comment: @shad12ow then you want craigs list which is commonly used to post for one off jobs. you could even have a turning point where your people move from the public list to the harder more shadowy jobs of the professional list.

Comment: @John Yes, craig lists is one of the alternative I'm also considering at first. But I was afraid that it has little opportunity due to the whole big corporation rule and all. But I do like that scenario you mentioned.

Comment: The more corporate control there is the bigger the market for jobs that don't fit a standard niche. Grey and black markets become more likely the more restrictive the government/corporations are. also consider something like the UK  handyman guild or japanese job lists for ronin. which are like craigslist with background check. Help wanted adds are more common now not less. just make a formal help wanted organizatioin that takes a small cut to facilitate the listings.

Answer (score 5):

The more corporate control there is the bigger the market for jobs that don't fit a standard niche. Grey and black markets become more likely the more restrictive the government/corporations are. Help wanted adds are more common now not less.

I could easily see something like a more formalized version of craigslist. I could even see a bit of humor when the adventurers ask the person they just saved to give them a good review on the site. like a formal help wanted organization that takes a small cut to facilitate the listings, with something like our own up or down vote for customers satisfaction. It could handle everything from handyman jobs, to gardening to bodyguard and small scale security services.

Such an organization could even be a front for more shady dealings, using code such as "alternative pest control" for hit jobs or "lost pet recovery" for kidnapping. There could even be a eye opening moment when the party moves from legit jobs to the real jobs once they have reached a certain amount of trust. Part of deeper jobs might even be using a broker who can put in the right code words to get what you want. Companies would still use it through an intermediary and I could see mercenary groups using it as a source for recruitment.

Comment: Even today there are certain code words that are used on sites like Craig's list for things that are either illegal or do not conform to the site's User Agreement.  So this is a very plausible answer.

Answer (score 2):

I could imagine such an organization as a sort of "minor league" affiliated with one of the main mercenary or security organizations, or possibly shared by two of them (which would open the possibility of intraorganization Mordor/Isengard type conflict).  B listers in the adventurers guild: new inexperienced people, difficult people, old or damaged people possibly fallen from the ranks of the main group.  I like the idea of one old guy always being selected for the escort job - seen as a cushy and desirable job.  The others speculate why he is always the one selected.

In addition to the adjunct "farm team" functions you describe and the odd jobs like escort or pickup this group should have some main thing it does which is not a thing the other groups do.

If there has been a fall of civilization or big war along the way, the adventurers could have a standing job exploring ruins and looking for treasure / tech etc.  Individuals get pulled off wrecksploring as needed for other jobs that come up but this role ensures they don't sit around idle too much.

Answer (score 1):

- In a cyberpunk world many major corporations will have their own [security departments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_guard#United_States_2). Then some suit with a MBA suggests to *outsource* the less critical functions -- the guards for the downtown sales office, but not the guards for the CEO or the main R&D facility. Imagine a security company which relies mostly on subcontractors. At the same time, imagine a strong [union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_guard#Security.2C_Police.2C_and_Fire_Professionals_of_America) presence. While this might sound un-cyberpunkish, perhaps the bosses made an exception for their rent-a-goons.
- Alternatively, start with an [express delivery service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_messenger), again using subcontractors, which grew with the cyberpunkish times to include armed escort for their deliveries (at a suitable surcharge).

---

*Postscriptum:*

- Some corporation could make it their business model to connect freelancers and customers, uber-style. They *might* provide some vetting of employers and employees, and services like insurance and payment escrow, but mostly they use their market position to make sure that there are no independents to undercut their prices.